# Trigger in mysql which doesnt allow duplicate values of certain pairs of columns

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

I want to create a trigger, which doesn't allow new inputs of (Dita AND Ora AND Salla) if they already exist in database as a group of values.

To be more specific, if a record exists with Hane, 12:00, 621. Do not allow it to be inserted!

Comment: I don't think you need a trigger for that, just create index for not to insert duplicates for those columns

Comment: It's one index, for all three columns to be unique

Comment: Are you saying that ids 3 and 4 should have been rejected?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE fiekorari
ADD UNIQUE INDEX duplli (Dita, Ora, Salla);
```